# How to make the sphero keep rotate on the spot?

Tags: rotation, sphero-api

I am new to Sphero development. I saw the app 'Drive' could make Sphero keep rotating before calibration. Anyone have idea how to make it?
I tried [RKRollCommand sendCommandWithHeading:90 velocity:0.01f stopped:YES] to adjust the header, but it just rotate 90 degree, anyway I could make it keep rotating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a rotate over time command paired with a delay in a macro, this is how we do it in the drive app.  MacroLab comes with at least one built in macro that demonstrates this.